# Camel RX is not deleting objects consumed from S3

Tags: java, apache-camel

If I configure Camel using a `RouteBuilder`:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("aws-s3://my-bucket?accessKey=******&secretKey=******")
                .to("stream:out");
    }
});
```

Then each object in the `my-bucket` is consumed and then immediately deleted.

However if I use [Camel RX](http://camel.apache.org/rx.html):

```
new ReactiveCamel(context).toObservable("aws-s3://my-bucket?accessKey=*****&secretKey=*****", String.class)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I find that objects are never deleted, the same objects are continually consumed.

The `S3Consumer` appears to have an ['`OnCompletion`' callback](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/aws/s3/S3Consumer.java#L136-L150) which will remove an object after it has been consumed. The callback is only called when using the `RouteBuilder` approach.

I expected both approaches to work similarly but it's clear I am missing something. Is it possible to make the 'reactive approach' delete the objects once they are consumed?

**EDIT:** I am using Camel 2.15.2.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.15.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah yeah thanks for spotting this. This is a bug in camel-rx and I have logged a ticket to get this fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8747

The UoW is not enabled when using camel-rx.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep an eye on the ticket.